# Adding new field to a struct in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct, field

I have a 800x1 struct `S` with fields `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` and `G`. I want to add an eighth field `H` where `H` is a matrix 800x8191 double. There is a 1x8191 row of `H` for every element of S.

That is, I want to make the assignment `S(i)=H(i,:)` for every `i`.

I tried `S.H=H` or `S.Hcalculated=H`, but received the error "Scalar structure required for this assignment."

How can I succeed?

Comment: "Every row of S" or of H?

Comment: Well, the k-th row of H should become the corresponding entry S.H(k)

Comment: You mean `S(k).H`?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness as it's not mentioned in other answers, you could of course just use a for loop. I don't really see a reason to avoid it:

```
for i = 1:size(H,1)
   S(i).H = H(i,:); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```matlab
S=arrayfun(@(s,h)setfield(s,'H',cell2mat(h)),S,num2cell(H,2));
```

For example,

```matlab
>> S=struct;
>> S.A='a';
>> S(2).A='b';
>> H=[1,2;3,4];
>> H=num2cell(H,2);
>> S=arrayfun(@(s,h)setfield(s,'H',cell2mat(h)),S,H'); % transpose is needed because the shape of S is 1x2
```

[image]

Note: if you need to perform row-wise operations on H, you should consider doing that first before appending its rows onto S for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps:

1. Separate the matrix `H` into a separate matrix for each row.
2. Assign the new matrices `H` to `S.H` using [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html).

Example:

This is example data, `S` is your struct (but of size 3x1 with only a field `A` for simplicity), `H` is a 3x10 array, where the first dimension matches the length of `S`:

```matlab
S = struct('A', {'a', 'b', 'c'})';
H = randn(3, 10);
```

The two steps described above:

```matlab
H = num2cell(H, 2);
[S.H] = deal(H{:});
```